# Backbone.js: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Hi I have a Collection which uses `fetch()` to do the initial fetch from the API. On a user's interaction, a second fetch is triggered, but instead of using the original `fetch()`, I used a `fetchNew()` that I defined myself:

**Collection**

```
ListingCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Listing,
    url: '/api/search_by_bounds',

    fetchNew: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        var collection = this,
            success = options.success;
        options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
            _(collection.parse(resp, xhr)).each(function(item) {
                // added this conditional block
                if (!collection.get(item.id)) {
                    // Update collection
                    collection.add(item, {silent:true});
                    // Render View
                    new ListingMarkerView({ model:item }).render();
                }
            });
            if (!options.silent) {
                collection.trigger('reset', collection, options);
            }
            if (success) success(collection, resp);
        };
        return (this.sync || Backbone.sync).call(this, 'read', this, options);
    }
});
```

This will add only the new Models to the collection, and render only the Views of these new Models. (if all the Views are removed and re-rendered, it will cause a flicker)

**View**

```
ListingMarkerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function() {
        var marker = L.marker([this.model.get('lat'), this.model.get('lng')]);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    },

    close: function() {
        this.unbind;
    }

});
```

**Error**

However I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'
```

which corresponds to this line in `ListingMarkerView`

```
var marker = L.marker([this.model.get('lat'), this.model.get('lng')]);
```

**Debug**

If I were to place a `console.log(item)` before the line that renders `ListingMarkerView`

```
console.log(item)
new ListingMarkerView({ model:item }).render();
```

I do see a valid `item`:

```
Object
    id: "2599084"
    lat: "42.276852"
    lng: "-71.165421"
    price: "2850"
    __proto__: Object
```

So...

**Question**

What seems to be the problem? How can this be solved? Thank you!

Comment: I'd rather go with usual `.reset`, why do you want to do that? Can you post a link to the working site so I can inspect?

Comment: Will `.reset` remove the items that were in the initial `fetch()` but not in the subsequent call? I wish to just append new models to the collection without removing the old ones.

Comment: If you want to add new ones without removing old ones, use `fetch({add:true})`. However you should still understand the answer I gave to your question, since it will definitely come up elsewhere.

Comment: Yes `fetch{add:true})` has the effect that I want, thanks! However, I still cant render the View after using `_.bindAll`

Comment: Again: Can you post a link to the working site so I can inspect?

Comment: I have it working now, just had to make `render` trigger on the `add` event, thanks @blockhead and @Miszy!

Comment: Oh, is there a way to only render the newly added model's views without re-renderieng the existing model's views?

Comment: If you listen for the `add` event on the collection, you can render like that.

Comment: Thanks, I attempted to do what you suggested, but I can't figure out how to access the new models. I started a new question, please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655913

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is render does not have `this` defined correctly.
Add a `initialize` method in the view class like this:

```
initialize: function() {
   _.bindAll(this); //Make all methods in this class have `this` bound to this class
}
```

Comment: I added `_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'close');` but got the same error

Comment: What is `this.model` equal to?

Comment: Great it works now! Using `add:true` and changing the render to trigger on `add` instead of `reset` which sounds strange to me

Comment: Please don't use this answer as is...it is considered bad practice, and is being deprecated and removed from underscore.

Comment: @blockhead - good to know, will do. For those wondering what the solution is, then, read the comments on the OP.