# Backbone.js: After doing Fetch(), render only the new models

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a Collection `App.listingList` where subsequent `fetch()` are called with `add:true`.

```
App.listingList.fetch({
        data: {some:data},
        processData: true,
        add: true
});
```

**Problem:** How can the newly added models have their views rendered, without re-rendering the views of the existing models. This means I cannot do:

```
this.collection.each( function(listing, index) {
    new ListingMarkerView({ model:listing }).render();
}, this);
```

**Attempt #1**

Rendering the View on the collection's `add` event, I cannot figure out a way to access the new models to render

```
ListingListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('add', this.renderNew, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('render ListingListView');
        this.collection.each( function(listing, index) {
            new ListingMarkerView({ model:listing }).render();
        }, this);
        return this;
    },

    renderNew: function() {
        // How do I grab the new models?
        new ListingMarkerView({ model:listing }).render(); // wont work
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Attempt #2**

I tried having a second Collection to do the subsequent `fetch` on, and compare the models of both collections using underscore.js's `_.without()`, but the array returned still contains the elements found in the 2nd array passed as the parameter. Using `_difference()` also returned the same array passed as the first array.

```
App.listingListNew.fetch({
        data: {some:data},
        processData: true,
        success: function() {
            console.log(App.listingListNew.models);
            console.log(App.listingList.models);
            console.log(_.without(App.listingListNew.models, App.listingList.models));
            console.log(_.difference(App.listingListNew.models, App.listingList.models));
        }
});
```

**`console.log` Output**

Since I passed in 2 identical arrays into `_.difference()` and `_.without()`, the output should be `[]`. But it isnt :/ Maybe because `cid` is different, so every one of them are treated as unique?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do a `collection.bind('add', this.renderNew, this);` it automatically passes the added model to your method as an argument.

Include the argument in your method and you should have access to the new model.

```
renderNew: function(newModel) {
    new ListingMarkerView({ model:newModel }).render();
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was having the same issue and came across this response so I thought I'd add an alternate approach.  I'm not sure how efficient it is, but it works.  I'm using this to support an infinite scroll feature.

I'm using Backbone 1.2.1, so in the collection fetch, I'm using `remove:false` instead of the deprecated `add:true` per the docs here: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

The basic approach is to set a `rendered` attribute to `true` on each item in the collection when first rendered, then use that to ignore previously rendered items on subsequent fetches.

Model and Collection:

```
MyApp.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});

MyApp.ItemList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: MyApp.Item,
    url: '/api/item/',
    parse : function(response){
        if (response.stat) {
            return _.map(response.content, function(model, id) {
                model.id = id;
                return model;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Views:

```
MyApp.ItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    className: 'item-list',
    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(item){
            //don't render items that have already been rendered!
            if (!item.rendered) {
                var itemListDetailView = new MyApp.ItemListDetailView({model: item});
                this.$el.append(itemListDetailView.render().el);
                item.rendered = true;
            }
        }, this)
        return this;
    }
});

MyApp.ItemListDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'item-list-detail',
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( '<div class="item-title">' + this.model.get('title') + '</div>');
        return this;
    }
});
```

Fetch function:

```
MyApp.loadMyItems = function () {
    MyApp.gettingData = true;  //flag for infinite scroll
    MyApp.myItems.fetch({
        traditional: true,
        remove:false,
        data: {
            u_id: MyApp.User.id,
            order: 'create_date:desc',
            start: MyApp.myItems.length,
            num_items: 10
        },
        success: function(){
           MyApp.gettingData = false; //flag for infinite scroll
           MyApp.myItemsView.render();
        }
    });
};
```

Calling:

```
//on initial page load
MyApp.myItems = new MyApp.ItemsCollection();
MyApp.myItemsView = new MyApp.ItemListView({
                            collection: MyApp.myItems, 
                            el: $('#my-items') 
                         });
MyApp.loadMyItems();

//infinite scroll
$('#items .infinite-scroll').on('loadmore', function () {
    if (!MyApp.gettingData) {
        MyApp.loadMyItems();
    } 
});
```